# ETL Glue delta or incremental logic

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, etl, aws-glue

Working on a project where we need to have an incremental load on daily basis, We are using Glue for the ETL purpose. We are getting duplicates or data getting doubled using Glue.

```
pipeline flow: Ingestion Zone, Raw Zone, Curated zone, consumption zone.
History: 1000 records. Below dates on updates and inserts
```

[image]

End of the Jan-11 run, `I would like to see my total records of 1100 records as I'm upserting the data in rawtocurated zone`. However, **I'm getting the doubled-up records in the curated zone**. The data is partitioned on a run date basis. like 2020/01/10/data.csv  and 2020/01/11/data.csv

What changes should I make to avoid only the delta records (or) incremental records to be seen in the comsumption zone?

Comment: Are you using the Job Bookmark Feature?

Comment: Yes . It is not working for the usecase.

Comment: Do you use Glue Meta Data Catalog?

Comment: Yes. Athena tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of problem statement : Glue job bookmarks feature is used along with the meta data catalog tables to ensure only new data is processed .
Few Queries :

1. Is your curated zone build on top of s3 or any other RDS services provided ?
2. Is is direct updates or SCD-2 data transformation ?
3. Have you by any chance reset/paused/disable the Job bookmarks ?
4. If you say data is partitioned on run-date basis so partitioning is applicable on ingestion layer [multiple date specific folders under on S3 bucket and data maintained in parquet format ] or on target curated layer ?

Even if that is not solving your problem that I would recommend you to write custom spark code using either pyspark/scala encapsulating your processing logics

Comment: 1. Curated zone on top of S3.
2. Upserts and SCD-2 are there for different data flows 
3. Haven't tried that.
4. Data partitioned on Rundate